# Strange error invoking ilaplace function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using `ilaplace` transform in matlab to compute the inverse Laplace transform of a function, however, I meet a strange error I cannot handle. Here is the output from matlab command line, where `>>` is the prompt. (`s` and `t` are `syms` symbolic variables)

```
>> N

N =

-(2.7071747341794232778783099808678e-34*(3.5938879023008902403763863659998e33*s - 68267793397927900578281423804583.0))/s^2

>> ilaplace(N)
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: The argument is invalid. [_concat]
  Evaluating: partfrac

Error in transform (line 74)
F = mupadmex('symobj::vectorizeSpecfunc', f.s, x.s, w.s, trans_func,
'infinity');

Error in sym/ilaplace (line 31)
F = transform('ilaplace', 's', 't', 'x', L, varargin{:});

>> ilaplace(-(2.7071747341794232778783099808678e-34*(3.5938879023008902403763863659998e33*s - 68267793397927900578281423804583.0))/s^2)

ans =

(23990078920530555628928726307903*t)/1298074214633706907132624082305024 - 4933332333844707562298796153537/5070602400912917605986812821504
```

The prblem is, if I directly invoke `ilaplace(N)`, I have an error. However, if I pass the expression to `ilaplace`, I have the right answer. I don't know why.

EDIT: The complete code file is as follows.

```
syms s  t;
syms s positive;
syms t positive;

tau = 4.2562313045743237429846099474892;

V_fitted = 1 - 1.015*exp(-0.0825*t);  % CDF function
V_fitted_right_shift = subs(V_fitted, t, t - tau);  % right shift CDF by tau

lambda_out = 1 / ( tau + int((1 - V_fitted_right_shift), [tau, Inf]) );  %arrival rate of the process

K = 4;  %number of processes

V_CDF_superposed = 1 - (1 - V_fitted_right_shift)*(lambda_out * int((1-V_fitted_right_shift), [t-tau, Inf]))^(K - 1); %new CDF 

FV_CDF_superposed = vpa(V_CDF_superposed);

Laplace_V_CDF_superposed = laplace(FV_CDF_superposed);  %laplace transform

N = Laplace_V_CDF_superposed/(1 - s * Laplace_V_CDF_superposed);    

N = vpa(N);  
N = simplify(N);

N_t = ilaplace(N);
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, how did you create/get `N`? Could you give that code as well?

Comment: @Daniel I wanted to detour this error so I revised the code, and after I changed it back, the error was gone! This is so strange!

Comment: @Daniel Oh, wait a minute~

Comment: @Daniel The complete code is added at the bottom of the question. Would you please have a look on this?